# 'Storing data in controller' app using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner to Angularjs. I am practicing by watching videos. I tried a program.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>

 </head>
<body >
    <div ng-Controller="StoreController as store">
        <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
        <h2>{{store.product.price}}</h2>
        <p>{{store.product.lastname}}</p>
    </div>
  <script type="javascript" src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/app.js" type="javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

saved as 'index.html' &

```
(function(){
 var app= angular.module('store',[]);
app.controller('StoreController', function()
    {this.product = gem;}
    );
var gem = {
    name : 'Deco',
    price : 2.5,
    lastname : 'ANIL KUMAR',
}
})();
```

Saved as app.js

but it is not showing data only showing

```
{{store.product.name}}
{{store.product.price}}
{{store.product.lastname}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your console log for errors. I see at least one error, the gem variable is lost because controller is called in future. Declare gem inside controller.

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('store', []);
    app.controller('StoreController', function () {
        var gem = {
            name: 'Deco',
            price: 2.5,
            lastname: 'ANIL KUMAR',
        }
        this.product = gem;
    });
})();
```

Comment: I tried the above method but results are same. Please suggest something to debug.

Comment: See in Browser developer console (F12) what error is logged.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variable 'gym' as a scope variable inside the controller. Please check this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ashraffayad/pdbrds7m/

```
var store = angular.module('myApp',[]);

store.controller('StoreController', ['$scope', function (scope) {
    scope.gym = {
        name: 'Deco',
            price: 2.5,
            lastname: 'ANIL KUMAR'}
        }]);


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-Controller="StoreController">
        <h1>{{gym.name}}</h1>
        <h2>{{gym.price}}</h2>
        <p>{{gym.lastname}}</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you Both of you. Both the codes are correct.
 After Debugging at every step finally i found the mistake.

```
<div ng-Controller="StoreController as store">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name"></input> 
        <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
        <h2>{{store.product.price}}</h2>
        <p>{{store.product.lastname}}</p>
    </div>
  <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/app.js"></script>
 &

(function(){
 var app= angular.module('store',[]);
app.controller('StoreController', function()
    {this.product = gem;}
    );
var gem = {
    name : 'Deco',
    price : 2.5,
    lastname : 'ANIL KUMAR',
}
})();
```

This is working now.